# Use a script for a telnet session

Tags: shell, expect, telnet

I have a problem with my script. It seems my password is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set ip [lindex $argv 0]
spawn telnet $ip
set timeout 10
expect "Login:"
send "administrator\r"
expect "Password:"
send "123456"
send "\r"
```

It says, `login incorrect`. But it works, when i use `cmd` on Windows to telnet to my phone, it works with "administrator" and 123456 as password.
I don't know why in my script, I could not log on successfully.

I have to use this script to downgrade/upgrade my phones.

Comment: Your directive /usr/bin/expecct has an extra c in it. That might not be causing the issue, but could you correct it and try?

Comment: Also, take a look at this link - http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/. The password could be in uppercase or lower case. Try this and see if it helps.

Comment: My password is only numbers :/ 
And sorry for the expecct, my bad, in my script it's expect.

Comment: You haven't send \r after your password, plus you have a send with /r instead \r

Comment: What i meant was the prompt could be either "Password:" or "password", can you try replacing the expect "Password:" with expect "*?assword:*"

Comment: If i put \r in send "789234\r"

The result on my screen after Password: *******
There is one more * . I don't know where it came.
When i put it after like i did:
send "789234" 
send "\r"
I have still login incorret but i have 6* like my password, and not 7.

I tried with "?assword" still not work

Comment: did you try with the lower case option? "password:"

Comment: I tried everything you said in comments. but i still have the problem :( with lower case, with {} like sharkguto said.

Comment: get expect to give you more info: add `exp_internal 1` after the #! line

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just have to put some

```
sleep
```

command before

```
expect "Login:"
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: It is possible to select one's own answer as "accepted". Do that.