# Telnet BASH script - output not saved

Tags: bash, telnet

I'm running a very simple telnet bash script and it works.

```
#!/bin/sh
host=90.205.177.129
port=23
login=admin
passwd=Sky.2015
#cmd1=sh
cmd2=meminfo > /tmp/top.txt

echo open ${host} ${port}
sleep 5
echo ${login}
sleep 5
echo ${passwd}
sleep 10
#echo ${cmd1}
#sleep 5
echo ${cmd2}
sleep 20
echo exit
```

However, the output of meminfo is not copied on "top.txt" file. The file is created

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/my_scripts# ls -l /tmp/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 784 Oct 13 14:32 1wall_test1_S.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 216 Oct 14 11:28 test_l.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 216 Oct 14 11:37 test_s.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Oct 15 09:35 top.txt
root@raspberrypi:/etc/my_scripts#
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `echo $foo` is not `eval "echo $foo"`.

Comment: `expect` is a better tool for this job than `bash`.  e.g. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184666/use-a-script-for-a-telnet-session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem lies in

`cmd2=meminfo > /tmp/top.txt`

this actualy sets the variable `cmd2` to *meminfo* and evaluates the  redirection. you should quote this.

`cmd2='meminfo > /tmp/top.txt'`

**edit:** this creates the file on the target. according to your own answer you wanted to create it on the system that runs the script (not stated in your original question). the cause is still valid, but the solution is not.

Comment: The problem is that I have to re-direct the output command not on the local machine but on the remote machine where I'm running the script

Comment: Yes, that is the scenario. I managed to get my output with 
./telnet.sh | telnet > /tmp/top.txt I
However, that command run every 5 minutes and every time it runs it overwrites the old file. How can I create and incremented file?

Comment: easy! Thak you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `alias cmd2="meminfo > /tmp/top.txt"` to create an alias command, instead of using an environment variable called `cmd2`.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you for your reply. How can I insert the alias in the script? Can you explain me why the variable is not good? Those are my first steps in scripting world and I would understand "why" :)Thank you

Comment: The alias should be created after you are connected to the telnet session, and then you just add `echo cmd2`. Unfortunately I can't reproduce, as the `open` command is different on CentOS or Ubuntu, but I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution by myself :)

```
./telnet.sh | telnet > /tmp/top.txt
```

In this way I redirect the command to an output file. However, I have to run the same script many times and I don't want overwrite the same file, but I would create and incremental file (good idea would be renamed with DATE command).

to use a date option

```
./telnet.sh | telnet > /tmp/top-$(date +%Y%m%d-%T).txt
```