# crontab -e not working

Tags: cron

I'm running these commands on crontab and it seems that the script are not running every 5 minutes

```
5 * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Jay.txt
5 * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet_lab.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Lab.txt
```

Comment: After the suggested corrections, are you getting any email from cron? Anything appearing in the files in /tmp ?

Answer (score 4):

`5 * * * * .../script` means to run `.../script` at 5 mins past every hour.

`*/5 * * * * .../script` means to run the script every 5 minutes.

Also, I'm not entirely sure whether the pipe to telnet will work in cron (it depends on whether your cron forks a shell to run your command or not).  You'd be better off rewriting your script so that the pipe to telnet occurs inside the script (which can be as simple as wrapping it in `( ... ) | telnet`....and you'd certainly be better off rewriting your script as an `expect` script rather than a shell script - expect is designed for exactly this kind of job.

Comment: here's an example of a telnet expect script: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184666/use-a-script-for-a-telnet-session

Comment: This is the correct answer, and yet it is at the bottom of the thread.

Answer (score 3):

You need another `*` before command

The columns are

```
mins, hrs, day of month, month of year, day of week, command
```

Comment: error corrected but still doesn't work. Any suggestion?

5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Jay.txt
5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet_lab.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Lab.txt

Answer (score 2):

You need one more `*`

The format is:

1. minute
2. hour
3. day-of-month
4. month
5. day-of-week
6. command

**Update**

Also if you just put `5` in the first field, your command will only be executed 5 minutes after the full hour. To have it executed every 5 minutes it should be `*/5`

Comment: error corrected but still doesn't work. Any suggestion?

5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Jay.txt
5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet_lab.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Lab.txt

Comment: Are `/etc/my_scripts/telnet.sh` and `/etc/my_scripts/telnet_lab.sh` executable?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236521/47864: 5 *... means to run it at five minutes past the hour. */5 * ... means to run it every five minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should have 5 fields :

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: error corrected but still doesn't work. Any suggestion?

5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Jay.txt
5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet_lab.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Lab.txt

Comment: In this case I think you should give us more informations : ) why you pipe telnet? what does your script do?

Comment: Did you tried to forget cron for a while and execute your script manually? It would make simpler to localize the problem

Answer (score -1):

You need to add one star. The crontab spec says that there are 5 fields for the time specification.

Comment: error corrected but still doesn't work. Any suggestion?

5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Jay.txt
5 * * * * /etc/my_scripts/telnet_lab.sh | telnet >> /tmp/top_Lab.txt

Comment: Cron usually sends you a mail with the status report for failing commands. Did you get such a mail?